# Converting EST to IST gives error in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am trying to convert EST( Eastern Standard Time) to IST (Indian Standard Time) but the conversion is showing incorrect results.
Can anyone help me on that??
I searched on net and found that using Noda time we can solve that.
But I want to solve it using conventional DateTime class.

Here is my code and its output:

```
DateTime time= new DateTime(1899,12,30, 23, 30 ,0); //some random date and 11:30 PM in EST

TimeZoneInfo estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"); // Eastern Time Zone

TimeZoneInfo istZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"); // Indian Time Zone

DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time, estZone, istZone); // result is 10:00 am while it should be 09:00 am.
```

Comment: What makes you think that the result you get is incorrect?

Comment: It may be using EDT instead of EST as most places just refer to the timezone as Eastern Time (ET) and leave the choice of standard or daylight to the converter.

Comment: @Fjodr I think its due to difference in daylight savings.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- The `TimeZoneInfo` identifier `"Eastern Standard Time"` refers to the North American Eastern Time zone, covering *both* Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight Time.  EST is UTC-5, while EDT is UTC-4.  In general, you should not infer too much from the names of these identifiers.  See more examples in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- The `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` method will use whichever offset is appropriate for the supplied date and time, correctly taking the [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) rules into account.
- The underlying time zone data from Windows does not go back to 1899.  There are actually no sources of data that guarantee historical dates from that time period.  Even [the IANA time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) used with [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) makes an educated guess.  See [History of DST in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#History_of_DST_in_the_United_States).
- Windows will just use the earliest data it has, which for this zone uses the daylight saving time rules that were in effect from 1986 to 2007.  These are not the current rules, so it would make better sense to use a modern year, such as `DateTime.Today.Year`.
- Even if you supplied a modern year, the correct converted time would indeed be 10:00 for a date in December.  If you want 9:00, try a date in the summer.